# Is it possible to get iOS app push settings with Phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I've created an app with Phonegap 1.6 and have successfully implemented an [Urban Airship Push Plugin](https://github.com/ckihneman/UACordova).

When the user runs the app for the first time, the device will ask the standard question "Do you want to allow this app to to send you notifications" (something like that). My question is: How do I know if the user answered yes or no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback of the [function](https://github.com/ckihneman/UACordova/blob/master/iOS/www/PushNotification.js#L7) responsible for asking the user whether he wants to enable PushNotifications contains all the data you'll need.

It'll look something like [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iOS/PushNotification/README.md#javascript-interface):

```
{"type":"7","pushBadge":"1","pushSound":"1","enabled":"1","deviceToken":"blablahblah","pushAlert":"1"}
```

You should execute this function on every App launch. If the User updates the push settings in the settings app you will immediately get the new data.

Note: The popup will appear only once, so calling the register function won't bring up the alert on every launch.